# I need to update my row in a dialogbox

Tags: android

At the moment the user in my app clicks on a row with details and a dialogbox pops up with the data that is required to be updated .I already have the update method in the database ,I'm just not sure how I'm supposed to implement it in the activity which is in `Edit_Activity`,could you give me advise on what I have to do next to update the strings.Thank you.[image]

*Edit_Activity*

```
    package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Edit_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        ListView listView;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
        DatabaseClass  database;
        Cursor cursor;
        ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
        Dialog d;

        Button updateBtn;
        EditText nameEditText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
            listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            database = new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext());

            sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor=database.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String id, product_name, category;
                    id = cursor.getString(0);
                    product_name = cursor.getString(1);
                    category = cursor.getString(2);
                    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, product_name, category);
                    listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()                            );

            }        
        }

        private void showDialog(){
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input);
            dialog.setTitle("Here Goes the Title");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position , long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_id);

            sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
        showDialog();
/*
        listView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                Button updateBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);

             /*   if (position == -1) {
                    updateBtn.setEnabled(false);
                } else

                    updateBtn.setEnabled(true);

                updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                  }  
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
});
*/
    /*private void displayInputDialog(final int pos) {
        d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("List View");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.input);

        final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        Button updateBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);

     if (pos == -1) {
          updateBtn.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
          updateBtn.setEnabled(true);
      }
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });*
        }*/
            }
        }
```

*DatabaseClass*

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

/**
 * Created by family on 06/07/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_Name = "Product.db2";
    public static final String Table_Name = "product_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Quantity";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Category";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Importance";
    Context myContext;

    public DatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_Name, null, 1);
    }

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,Quantity TEXT,Category INTEGER,Importance TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

   public boolean insertData(String name, String quantity, String category,String importance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name, null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
        db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
                return true;
    }

   /* public Cursor getCursor(){
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setR
    }
*/
   public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(Table_Name,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
   }
    public static void DeleteInformation(String item_name, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(Table_Name,selection,selection_args);
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_4};

        cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }

    public Cursor getItem(String item_name ,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5};
        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }


}
```

Comment: instead of creating a `Dialog` directly, you'll want to create a custom dialog class, android dev website already has a pretty good guide on this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

Comment: @quidproquo Thanks, I ll do that then!

Comment: @quidproquo I created the custom dialog ,it's working but I'm still not sure how to implement the update,can you give me some advice about that please?